# Very large number of SQL UNION SELECT statements exceeds max_stack_depth

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to develop a spatial based SQL query of all unique points within one or more of a given set of polygons. I am using PostGIS on a cloud VPS with 6 vCPU's and 16 GB of RAM. The spatial test in question is ST_Contains on the WHERE clause. The polygon set is approximately 40,000 unique geometries that constrain the 3.7 million feature point dataset.

My problem is that when I create a query with more than 13,000 polygons (an therefore 13,000 SELECT statements) the PostGIS server responds with an `ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded"`
`HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth"`.

**I want to know why and if I have options to work around it.**

This is part of an optimization exercise. I'm already retrieving the polygon geometries as a separate SELECT to form the required SQL query. I want to execute the query that tests the polygon set as a single SQL statement. So far I have been building a SELECT subquery for each polygon then UNION each together as a start point. When compiled, the query using only 13,000 polygons is ~28,000,000 characters which I believe is much less than the PostGIS SQL statement limit.

I have tried smaller sizes and found that there is normal performance right up to the approximate limit. I had hit this limit earlier but after taking the advice of the error message I increased the "max_stack_depth" to approximately the size of what "ulimit -s" returns. At my current understanding, this SQL statement is not a recursive function of any kind which is what I would expect to cause the stack depth to be exceeded.

Also from my reading around stack vs heap memory, I cannot understand why this query would overload the stack as most of the required stored data should end up in the heap. I also expect the query to execute sequentially while collecting the results but it seems like PostGIS might be running all the SELECT substatements first then tallying up the results.

I have chosen to not try to merge the individual polygon geometries into a single polygon as they cover a very geographically diverse area (i.e not clustered into a simple mass) which I believe would drastically decrease benefits from spatial indexing.

My current working SQL script follows the pattern (trimmed to fit on this post):

```
SELECT * FROM point_table WHERE ST_Contains("poly1_geom_str", pt_geom_col)
UNION
SELECT * FROM point_table WHERE ST_Contains("poly2_geom_str", pt_geom_col)
UNION
....
SELECT * FROM point_table WHERE ST_Contains("polyN_geom_str", pt_geom_col);
```

Is my strategy for constructing this SQL statement unlikely to be able to be resolved? Is there an alternative strategy I can try that would avoid the recursion problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this variant of your query. It creates a temporary table from the different polygon strings, and then performs a join based on `ST_Contains`:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT point_table.* 
FROM    point_table 
JOIN    (values ("poly1_geom_str"), 
                ("poly2_geom_str")
        ) as polys(poly_str)
     ON ST_Contains(poly_str, pt_geom_col)
```

Of course, if those geometrics actually come from an existing table, then just join that table:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT point_table.* 
FROM    point_table 
JOIN    polys
     ON ST_Contains(poly_str, pt_geom_col)
```

Comment: Can you explain why the distinct ?

Comment: A point could maybe be in more than one polygon, and then this query would list that point as many times. `distinct` prevents that.

Comment: @RémiDesgrange: the UNION from the original query also implies a DISTINCT

Comment: @trincot This has allowed me to exceed the prior limit and successfully completed the full query of 40,000. However, I'd still like to understand what was happening in the background that is causing my original query to fail in the exact manner it does.

Comment: I don't know about the internals of PostgreSQL/PostGIS to answer that, but it is understandable that a large SQL statement with 13,000 `union` operations will have a huge impact already in the compiling and optimisation phase of the engine (even before executing). Others have had similar experiences with such large queries. See for example [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/24361.1352654544%40sss.pgh.pa.us) where the error is reported with a 8000x`union all` query that is GIS independent.

Comment: @trincot thanks for that link. It doesn't leave me with a detailed understanding but it does look like the way PostgreSQL handles many UNIONs does invoke some recursion, perhaps as an optimization. It does leave me with the feeling not to try that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `or`?

```
SELECT *
FROM point_table
WHERE ST_Contains("poly1_geom_str", pt_geom_col) OR
      ST_Contains("poly2_geom_str", pt_geom_col) OR
      ....
      ST_Contains("polyN_geom_str", pt_geom_col);
```

Comment: I had tried this, sorry I didn't add that to the OP. This strategy will work for small numbers of polygons but will be rapidly limited by compute resources as the number of polygons increases. I believe this is because, for each additional polygon, the extra ST_Contains() function will scan the entire point table again. This strategy was only able to complete approximately 1000 polygons.